# Money Transfer by Indian Citizen to US Citizen to Settle a Debt

Tags: united-states, india, loans, money-transfer, transfer

I am a US Citizen. I sent money to help out a relative (an Indian Citizen) in India. I used Western Union to transfer the funds from the US -- I paid in USD and he received the remittance in Rupees. He is to pay me back as this was a loan. Can he repay the money back to me in USD through Western Union or some other means? Are there any restrictions or limits? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a written and signed loan agreement in place?

Comment: No. Only and oral agreement. I do have the money transfer records though, from Western Union.

Comment: The situation was a medical emergency ... under the circumstances and given the nature of the relationship, I could not ask for a loan agreement.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there is proper documentation.

Loan can only be credited to your NRO account.

See [RBI regulation](https://m.rbi.org.in/Scripts/BS_ViewMasterDirections.aspx?id=10191#C2)

> Persons Resident in India borrowing in INR from NRIs/PIOs
>
> 2.1 Available routes for borrowing: Persons resident in Indian may borrow in INR from NRIs/PIOs under the following two routes:
>
> 2.1.1 Borrowing in INR by persons other than companies in India: A person resident in India, not being a company incorporated in India,
>   may borrow in INR from NRIs/PIOs after satisfying the following terms
>   and conditions:
>
> Borrowing shall be only on a non-
>   repatriation basis;
>
> The amount of loan should be received either by inward remittance from
>   outside India or by debit to NRE/NRO/FCNR(B)/NRNR/NRSR account of the
>   lender, maintained with an authorised dealer or an authorised bank in
>   India;
>
> Period of loan shall not exceed 3 years;
>
> Rate of interest on the loan shall not be more than two per cent above
>   Bank Rate prevailing on the date of availment of loan;
>
> Payment of interest and repayment of principal shall be made only to
>   the NRO account of the lender.